# Copying pixels directly into GPU memory with PBO in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, gpgpu, pbo

I read it should be possible to transfer pixel data directly inside the GPU memory using pixel buffer objects. What I'm not understanding is if PBO is supported in OpenGL ES 2.0. I found incoherent information. Is PBO supported under OpenGL ES 2.0?

If not, is there any other way with OpenGL ES 2.0 to place data (RGBA32) directly into a texture?

Comment: Keep in mind that even with a PBO you cannot place data directly into a texture. You can place data in a PBO (probably stored on the GPU) and then copy this data into a texture (with the usual `glTexImage2D`), which is then copied asynchronously (and probably faster, because it's GPU -> GPU). Maybe you already know that, but your last sentence is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly not, it depends on the video graphics hardware driver you are using.  Texas Instruments has provide a bc-cat driver to do the job on  OMAP35x and AM35x platforms. Other company like Freescale , do not provide the same function.  For opengl es standard, this function is not defined.